# Why is spdiag deprecated in Octave, but not speye?

Tags: octave, identity, deprecated, sparse-matrix, diagonal

I've noticed that spdiag is deprecated, but not speye.  Why is this?  Both diag and eye generate diagonal matrices, so shouldn't speye be unnecessary as well (or at least exactly as unnecessary as spdiag)?

Answer (score 0):

You must be using an old version of Octave if that function is deprecated. It has already been removed in the last 5 releases (all 5 minor versions since 3.6.0).

Anyway, to address your question `spdiag()` does not return a sparse matrix, it does exactly  the same as `diag()`. To get a sparse diagonal matrix use `spdiags()`.

Comment: I'm using 3.2.4 (the version available in Ubuntu's repo), spdiag() does indeed return a sparse matrix.  spdiag(1:5) gives a sparse 5x5 matrix where the main diagonal is the numbers 1 through 5.